# Does Django automatically URL decode values

Tags: python, django

If I have a django app that accepts data at `/XXXX/`, will Django pass me (in the view) the url-decoded or url-encoded data?

Mock-up Example:

```
def view(req, s):
    return HttpResponse("Is this URL-decoded? : " + s)

urlpatterns = [
   ...,
   path('<str:s>/', view),
   ...,
]
```

Comment: Django will have parsed and decoded the URL by the time you handle the request.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of `s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No. Django passed the url "AS IS" and DO NOT encodes or decodes it on its own.

For `HttpResponse` object, Based on this:

> In contrast to HttpRequest objects, which are created automatically by Django, HttpResponse objects are your responsibility. Each view you write is responsible for instantiating, populating, and returning an HttpResponse.

from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects), Django sets the parameter values exactly the same as what you provide (you may refer this as "the decoded one"). If you need to decode the url, you can use the code below (Python 3+):

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
url = "http://..."
urllib.unquote(url)
```

And for encoding:

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode
urlencode(url)
```